# iOS: MasksToBounds not working during Flip Animation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cliptobounds

I am trying to flip a view and show a different view with an animation looking like flipping a card around.

This all worked well. I made one Parent View that nested 2 child views, these child views are the ones which get flipped. My Parent View has Rounded Corners through(layer.cornerRadius = x) and through layer.masksToBounds the child views don't go over the Bounds of the Parent view.

Anyway when I flip the views during this animation the corners are not rounded. I thought this is probably because when the flip happens the child views don't clip over the parent even with square corners, but then I also tried to add a cornerRadius to the Child Views which again did not work in my case because one of the Child Views nests itself child Views which then clip over the bounds again, which I don't understand at all!

I wrote a function to flip the views:

```
private func flip(firstView: UIView, secondView: UIView) {

     let transitionOptions: UIViewAnimationOptions = [.transitionFlipFromRight, .showHideTransitionViews]
    UIView.transition(with: firstView, duration: 1.0, options: transitionOptions, animations: {
        firstView.isHidden = !firstView.isHidden
    })

    UIView.transition(with: secondView, duration: 1.0, options: transitionOptions, animations: {
        secondView.isHidden = !secondView.isHidden
    })
}
```

For the rounded corners I just added a user defined runtime attribute in storyboard: layer.cornerRadius Number 13, as well as layer.masksToBounds Boolean true

I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: could you maybe provide a minimal example that can be used to replicate the problem?

Comment: okay, just did that now, hope you can help

Comment: Not sure if it will work but try to set Clip to bounds on the parent view on IB.

Comment: tried that already but still the same problem

Comment: It almost seems like clip to bounds turns of during anmation or something similar to that, because when I round corners at one child that does not have children itself it works for this view but if I try the same for view that has children these children again dont clip to the bounds (and I cannot round corners to all children in my case)

Comment: @uhuru hey could you upvote this question if you cannot answer it?

Comment: @SirJoe yeah done, i tried myself a bit but couldn't find a solution for you sorry. let's see if someone else.

Comment: Thanks a lot though for trying

Comment: @MilanNosáľ  hey could you upvote this question if you cannot answer it, would help a lot

Comment: @SirJoe When I was asking an example, I meant a complete code that could be compiled and run, ideally with a minimal code base (just the things necessary to replicate the issue) - playgrounds project maybe..

Comment: Okay I am not near a computer right now but once I am I will do that